# artisan migrate:rollback error in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-migrations, artisan-migrate

I'm trying to build a simple migration table and then trying to add a column in the table so following is my migration file:

```
class AddFlagToEmiTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('epins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('flag');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */ 
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('epins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

In this I forgot to write the drop value which is:

```
$table->dropColumn('flag');
```

Now while adding this and trying to `rollback` and again the trying to do `php artisan migrate` it is showing error, and also it is showing output nothing to migrate respectively even I've added drop values in the migration.

I've already tried following:

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```

It ain't helping me out please see the screenshot:

[image]

Help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because artisan cannot find `flag` column in `epins` table

There is workaround for this,

add `flag`column explicitly from phpmyadmin(if you are using mysql)  and then try roll back

Hope this method works, ask if any doubt

Comment: great , dont forget to mark it as answer, so it may help others also

Answer (score 0):

Please try deleting the tables from the database, modify the migration files and add drop to the down function and migrate again.

Comment: you mean I need to delete the whole migration file? or only the `add_flag_to_epins_table`. As I'm adding the column.

Comment: go to your phpmyadmin and add the flag column manually. `ALTER TABLE epins
ADD flag boolean`